# how to create some year/month/day path when uploading files with django

Tags: python, django

I have model like this:

```
class Obs(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Date')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
    content = models.FileField(verbose_name='File', upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
    category = models.ForeignKey(ObsType, related_name='Type', verbose_name='type')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User')
```

I need to set 'upload_to' path to 'date' field but this date is not current date.
How should I do this?

**UPDATE**

I solve it with function like:

```
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    date = unicode(instance)
    date = date.split()[0]  # to delete Time
    date = date.split('-')
    return '%s/%s/%s/%s' % (date[0], date[1], date[2], filename)
```

In my case Date is represented like 2014-01-04.
If it will be 2014/01/04 there will be error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use custom method to specify `upload_to` path, like this:

```
def get_obs_upload_path(instance, filename):
    my_custom_date = datetime.now()
    return '%s/%s' % (my_custom_date, filename)

class Obs(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, verbose_name='Date')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Description')
    content = models.FileField(verbose_name='File', upload_to=get_obs_upload_path)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ObsType, related_name='Type', verbose_name='type')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='User')
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I put date from class into this function?

Comment: You can use ``instance`` variable, which is passed to ``get_obs_upload_path()``.

Comment: Can you please write example? I dont know how it works. I try  upload_to=get_upload_to(date) but its fails. I am getting directory name "<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField>"

Comment: Pass a method instead of calling it. ``upload_to=get_upload_to`` instead of ``upload_to=get_upload_to(date)``.